# What cells and how many of those are infected and destroyed as a result of COVID-19 vaccine?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

My understanding is that cells modified by COVID-19 vaccines will eventually get killed by immune system. Do we know what cells are usually targeted by vaccines and how many of those get killed as a result of a single vaccine dose?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/26252/13428

Comment: @endolith - I don’t see that question covering “how many” and “which” cells are affected?